# Getting a "No enclosing instance of type..." error

Tags: java, object, subclass, abstract

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
public abstract class BoardTestBean{
    protected String month;
    protected String day;
    protected String name;


    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
    public String getYear() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setYear(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


    //Classes
    public class SAT {
        boolean pre2005=false;
        private String verbal;
        private String quantitative;
        private String writing="";//if pre-2005, do not set. It is not used. 

        public SAT() {
            super();
            if(pre2005)
                name="SAT (pre 2005)";
            else
                name="SAT";             
        }
        public SAT(String verbal, String quantitative, String writing) {
            super();
            this.verbal = verbal;
            this.quantitative = quantitative;
            if(writing!=null && !writing.isEmpty())
                this.writing = writing;
            else
                pre2005=true;
            if(pre2005)
                name="SAT (pre 2005)";
            else
                name="SAT"; 
        }
        public String getVerbal() {
            return verbal;
        }
        public void setVerbal(String verbal) {
            this.verbal = verbal;
        }
        public String getQuantitative() {
            return quantitative;
        }
        public void setQuantitative(String quantitative) {
            this.quantitative = quantitative;
        }
        public String getWriting() {
            if(!this.pre2005)
                return writing;
            else
                return "";
        }
        public void setWriting(String writing) {
            this.writing = writing;
        }
        public boolean isPre2005() {
            return pre2005;
        }
        public void setPre2005(boolean pre2005) {
            this.pre2005 = pre2005;
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps saying:

> No enclosing instance of type AddBoardTestCommand.BoardTestBean is
>   accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of
>   type AddBoardTestCommand.BoardTestBean (e.g. x.new A() where x is an
>   instance of AddBoardTestCommand.BoardTestBean).

when I try to do this:
    SAT bean = new SAT();
with SAT imported as `AddBoardTestCommand.BoardTestBean.SAT`

I don't understand why it is asking me to initialize the `BoardTestBean` class when it is abstract. It is meant to just hold the values for several subclasses (SAT is not the only subclass. I just omitted the others for simplicity).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No enclosing instance of type Server is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901941/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-server-is-accessible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `SAT` class is an *inner class* of `BoardTestBean`, but not a *static inner class*. Only static inner classes can be instantiated without an "enclosing" instance context; non-static need a "parent" instance.

If `SAT` does not need to use any of the `BoardTestBean`'s state, declare it `static`; otherwise, add an instance method to `BoardTestBean` and instantiate `SAT` from there.

P.S. I am assuming that you are accessing `SAT` from the same package, because it has *package visibility*. If this is not intentional, you will need to make the class `public` as well.

**EDIT** This is how you add an instance method to `BoardTestBean` returning `SAT`:

```
SAT makeSAT() {
    return new SAT();
}
```

Now outside `BoardTestBean` you can do this:

```
// assuming that you have an instance of BoardTestBean...
BoardTestBean myBean = ...
BoardTestBean.SAT = myBean.makeSAT();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "If it does not use any of the BoardTestBean's state"? It does uses the variable `name` from the superclass. It also uses the getMonth and getYear methods.

Comment: @Nacht `BoardTestBean` is not a superclass of SAT, it is its *enclosing* class. I edited the answer to show you an example of how you can approach the solution in non-static case.

Comment: Unn, your answer does work, but it makes it more complex than I expected it to be (the original idea was to make it compact and easy to debug in the future). Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You defined an inner class which has an hidden this to its outer class.

Just do

```
public static class SAT {
```

and you get an nested class without the hidden this