# Instantiate subclass of abstract class

Tags: java, class, instantiation, abstract

how do I instantiate the sub class of an abstract class? it gives error -- no enclosing instance of type abstractclass is accessible. no matter how I interchange the values. I know I cant use motorvehicle cuz abstract class cant be instantiated....

```
public class abstractclass {
public static void main(String args[]){

    Car car1 = new Car();   

}
abstract class MotorVehicle
{

    int fuel;


    int getFuel()
    {
         return this.fuel;
    }


    abstract void run();


}

class Car extends MotorVehicle
{
    void run()
    {

        System.out.print("Wrroooooooom");
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Here Car class is an inner class for abstractclass. so you can instantiate inner class like this only if its declared as static

Let's change your Program:

```
public class Abstract {
public static void main(String args[]){

    Car car1 = new Car();   

}
abstract class MotorVehicle
{

    int fuel;


    int getFuel()
    {
         return this.fuel;
    }


    abstract void run();


}

static class Car
{
    void run()
    {

        System.out.print("Wrroooooooom");
    }


}
}
```

Here Car class i declared as static and it can be instantiated inside "abstractclass".

For further reference you can look into [Getting a "No enclosing instance of type..." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931479/getting-a-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-error)

Answer (score 2):

It won't let you instantiate them because you've declared them as inner classes. Precede the class declarations with `static` and you'll be able to do it:

```
class Outer {

    class Inner {

    }

    static class Nested {

    }
}
```

If a nested class is *inner* (non-static), it belongs to instances of the outer class, not the outer class itself. Inner classes need an instance of the outer class to be instantiated. Static nested classes do not.

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
Outer.Nested nested = new Outer.Nested();
```

See [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) tutorial. That is what the "no enclosing instance" message is about. You are right that an abstract class can't be instantiated directly, but `Car` isn't abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:
public class abstractclass {

And also ending } from end of the file.

You have wrapped your whole program into one abstract class. Thats just wrong :).

Comment: so I must put main function on a separate class file too?