# ERROR: No enclosing instance of type OOPTutorial is accessible

Tags: java

I am new to Java and trying to do a simple program to help me further understand object-orientated programming.

I decided to do a phone program. However on line 5 of the following program where I'm trying to create an instance of a phone class I am getting the following error:

"No enclosing instance of type OOPTutorial is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type OOPTutorial (e.g. `x.new A()` where `x` is an instance of `OOPTutorial`)."

Here is the program:

```
public class OOPTutorial {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        phone myMobile = new phone();           // <-- here's the error
        myMobile.powerOn();
        myMobile.inputNumber(353851234);
        myMobile.dial();

   }

   public class phone{
       boolean poweredOn = false;
       int currentDialingNumber;

       void powerOn(){
           poweredOn = true;
           System.out.println("Hello");
       }
       void powerOff(){
           poweredOn = false;
       System.out.println("Goodbye");
       }
       void inputNumber(int num){
       currentDialingNumber = num;
       }
       void dial(){
           System.out.print("Dialing: " + currentDialingNumber);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: [off topic ]: you should name your classes using UppercaseStartingCamelCase. That is, your "phone" class should be "Phone".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No enclosing instance of type Server is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901941/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-server-is-accessible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not make sense to you if you're new to Java, but a instantiating a non-static inner class (`phone`) requires an instance of the enclosing class (`OOPTutorial`).

In plain English, this roughly means that you either

1. Can only do `new phone()` inside a OOPTutorial-method that is not marked as `static`, or
2. you need to make `phone` a top level class (i.e. move it outside the scope of `OOPTutorial`), or
3. you need to make the inner class `phone` as static (by putting `static` in front of the class declaration)

Comment: Given he's a beginner, would you like to add a bit more explanation? (ie an inner class has an implicit reference to the enclosing class - but there is none because it's called from a static method).

Comment: Thanks guys now I understand and the program runs :D