# No enclosing instance of type ITask is accessible.

Tags: java

I would like to make abstract class which has several inner classes extend it and could create  instances of its inner classes via static methods but I get compiler error "No enclosing instance of type ITask is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ITask (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of ITask)."

I've [found out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) that inner classes should be created by instances of outer class but my outer class has abstract method and I can't create instance of it. I made inner classes which extend parent because I wont to control creation of them.
So is there any way how to make my pattern works.

My code:

```
public abstract class ITask {
public abstract void Execute(Subscriber itm);

static public ITask CreateSendTask(Buffer buffer)
{
    return new SendData(buffer);
}

static public ITask CreateSTTask(Ticket sid)
{
    return new StartTransmission(sid);
}

static public ITask CreateETTask(Ticket sid)
{
    return new EndTransmission(sid);
}


private class SendData extends ITask
{
         /// some implemetation...
}

private class StartTransmission extends ITask
{
         /// some implemetation...
}

private class EndTransmission extends ITask
{
    /// some implemetation...
}
```

}

The problem is with methods Create(.*)Task.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901941/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-server-is-accessible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner classes should be made static if they're created from static methods, and thus don't need access to an enclosing ITask.

You should also respect Java naming conventions: methods start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: What does it mean static class in java? How it will be located in memory? Is it possible to have members in such class?

Comment: static inner classes are just like regular, top-level classes, except their name is EnclosingClass.InnerClass. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html