# No enclosing instance of type Camera is accessible

Tags: java, android, camera

Hi everyone I am developing an application where I need to use the Camera and I'm having this problem on my code:

> No enclosing instance of type Camera is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Camera (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Camera) on line "this.preSize_ = new Camera(0,0); 
>   Any help? or suggestion?

```
private void setupCamera()
  {
    this.camera_ = Camera.open();
    Camera localCamera = this.camera_;
    localCamera.getClass();
    this.preSize_ =  new Camera.Size(0,0);
    Camera.Parameters localParameters = this.camera_.getParameters();
    Iterator<Camera.Size> localIterator1 = localParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().iterator();
    Camera.Size localSize2;
    do
    {
      if (!localIterator1.hasNext())
        break;
      localSize2 = (Camera.Size)localIterator1.next();
      this.preSize_ = localSize2;
    }
    while ((localSize2.width != this.previewWidth) && (localSize2.height != this.previewHeight));
    localParameters.setPreviewSize(this.preSize_.width, this.preSize_.height);
    Iterator<Camera.Size> localIterator2 = localParameters.getSupportedPictureSizes().iterator();
    Camera.Size localSize1;
    do
    {
      if (!localIterator2.hasNext())
        break;
      localSize1 = (Camera.Size)localIterator2.next();
      this.procSize_ = localSize1;
    }
    while ((localSize1.width != this.processWidth) && (localSize1.height != this.processHeight));
    localParameters.setPictureSize(this.procSize_.width, this.procSize_.height);
    this.camera_.setParameters(localParameters);
    this.camera_.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    try
    {
      this.camera_.setPreviewDisplay(this.surfaceHolder_);
      this.camera_.startPreview();
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
      while (true)
        localException.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the type of `this.preSize_`? Is the nested class `Camera.Size`  static or not? (If not, you can only create it in the context of a `Camera` object).

Comment: @Jesper: Any suggestion? on `this.preSize`

Comment: Which `Camera` class are you importing?  There are two `Camera` classes in Android: `android.hardware.Camera` and `android.graphics.Camera` I have had a problem in the past where Eclipse would automatically import the wrong one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No enclosing instance of type Server is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901941/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-server-is-accessible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 3):

Size class is a non-static class of Camera. So you can create it only from enclosing instance of Camera class. Like this:

```
this.preSize_ = localCamera.new Size(0,0);
```

Comment: But I got an error telling : localCamera cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: same here for me? found any solution on that?

Comment: Camera localCamera = Camera.open();

Comment: @Sonhja since Size class never uses enclosing instance of the Camera so it looks like a bug. This API is deprecated since API 21 btw.