# a coding about reflection has a error "No enclosing instance of type student is accessible"

Tags: java

here is my coding about reflection:

```
public class student {
private String name;

public student(){
this.name = "Elodie";   
}
public String getName(){return name;}

class teacher {
private String name;
public teacher(){
    this.name = "Lady Lee";
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}

public static class reflect{
public static void main(String[] args)
{student student = new student();
 teacher teacher = new teacher();

 System.out.println(student.getClass().getName() + " " + student.getName());
 System.out.println(teacher.getClass().getName() + " " + teacher.getName());
}
}
}
```

I got one error message "No enclosing instance of type student is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type student (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance 
 of student)."

at `teacher teacher = new teacher();`

Since i want my coding result look like: student Elodie
                                         teacher Lady Lee

so i cannot write like student.new teacher() even if it works.

Btw, can anyone explain a bit about reflection based on my coding? I just know we can use reflection to get info of other classes as long as we know the name of the class.

Comment: There's no reflection in your code, and the error is not about reflection. The error comes from the fact that `teacher` is nested inside `student` and is not a static class. Follow a tutorial on the topic and that will make sense.

Comment: @vanza But after I change teacher to a static class, the result only looks like :student Elodie                                                       
            student$teacher Lady Lee

Comment: possible duplicate of [No enclosing instance of type Server is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901941/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-server-is-accessible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting because you're trying to initialize an instance of an inner class.

The inner class can be of 4 types:

1. Static
2. Method Local
3. Anonymous
4. Other then above these normal inner class

For more info on inner class, see this [link](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/inner-class/).

In your code, you've used normal inner class. To make an instance of it, replace the following:

```
teacher teacher = new teacher();
```

with the following:

```
teacher teacher = student.new teacher();
```

In order to get your desired result, replace the following:

```
System.out.println(teacher.getClass().getName() + " " + teacher.getName());
```

with the following:

```
System.out.println(teacher.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + teacher.getName());
```

As far as reflection is concerned, refer to the comment given by vanza.

Hope this info helps you.

Comment: Hi just FYI, I changed `getName` to `getSimpleName` and it works! But if i replaced `new teacher()` with `student.new teacher` it says "Illegal enclosing instance specification for type student.teacher". But anyway it works, thanks.