# Why do I get the compiler error "No enclosing instance of type ex4 is accessible"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having trouble in my `main` method. On the line `MyInt r1 = new MyInt(2);` I get a compiler error with the message: "No enclosing instance of type ex4 is accessible".

```
public class ex4 {
    public class MyInt implements Comparable<MyInt> { 
        private int value;

        MyInt(int x){ this.value= x;}

        public String toString() {
            return ("Result: " + intValue());
        }

        public int intValue() { return value; }

        public int compareTo(MyInt rhs){
            if ( value >rhs.value ){
                return 1;}
            if (value < rhs.value){
                return -1;}
            else return  0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInt r1 = new MyInt(2); //Error here ("No enclosing instance of type ex4 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ex4 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of ex4)."
        MyInt r2 = new MyInt(7); // same here
        System.out.println(r1.compareTo(r2));
    }
}
```

I've seen other responses to similar questions but I'm unable to solve my own issue, could anyone help? I'm trying to compare one value to another.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your actual issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No enclosing instance of type Server is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901941/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-server-is-accessible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyInt` is declared as an inner class, and can't be used in a static context. Change it to:

```
public static class MyInt
```

From the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> A *static nested class* is associated with it's outer class, and is `static`.
>
> An *inner class* is associated with *an instance* of it's enclosing class.

The relevant section of the JLS is [§8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple.