# Java Account program - No Enclosing Instance of Type is Accessible

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

Line 07 - I'm getting the following error:

> No enclosing instance of type Exercise10_7 is accessible

How can I resolve this?  Also, after finishing this I need to modify it to hold an array of 10 accounts with a 4 option menu (check balance, withdraw, deposit, exit).  If I could get some guidance on accomplishing this that would be awesome.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Exercise10_7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Account account1 = new Account(1122, 20000, .045);
    account1.withdraw(2500);
    account1.deposit(3000);
    java.util.Date dateCreated = new java.util.Date();

    System.out.println("Date Created:" + dateCreated);
    System.out.println("Account ID:" + account1.id);
    System.out.println("Balance:" + account1.getBalance());
    System.out.println("Interest Rate:" + account1.getAnnualInterestRate());
    System.out.println("Balance after withdraw of 2500:" +       account1.getAnnualInterestRate());
    System.out.println("Balance after deposit of 3000:" + account1.getAnnualInterestRate());
    System.out.println("Monthly Interest:" + account1.id);
    System.out.println("Process completed.");
    }

    class Account {
        //define variables
        private int id;
        private double balance; // balance for account
        private double annualInterestRate; //stores the current interest rate
        private Date dateCreated; //stores the date account created

        //no arg construtor
        Account () {
            id = 0;
            balance = 0.0;
            annualInterestRate = 0.0;
        }
        //constructor with specific id and initial balance
        Account(int newId, double newBalance) {
            id = newId;
            balance = newBalance;
        }
        Account(int newId, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate) {
            id = newId;
            balance = newBalance;
            annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
        }
        //accessor/mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public double getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }
        public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
            return annualInterestRate;
        }
        public void setId(int newId) {
            id = newId;
        }
        public void setBalance(double newBalance) {
            balance = newBalance;
        }
        public void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
            annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
        }
        //accessor method for dateCreated
        public void setDateCreated(Date newDateCreated) {
            dateCreated = newDateCreated;
        }
        //define method getMonthlyInterestRate
        double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
            return annualInterestRate/12;
        }
        //define method withdraw
        double withdraw(double amount) {
            return balance -= amount;
        }   
        //define method deposit
        double deposit(double amount) {
            return balance += amount;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No enclosing instance of type Server is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901941/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-server-is-accessible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0):

Because `Account` is an inner class, you need an instance of the enclosing class to incarnate it. Or you could make `Account` a static class. You could either change

```
class Account {
```

to

```
static class Account {
```

**or** change

```
Account account1 = new Account(1122, 20000, .045);
```

to

```
Account account1 = new Exercise10_7().new Account(1122, 20000, .045);
```

[JLS-8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) says (in part)

> An *inner class* is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared `static`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  So explicitly declaring is "static class Account" and implicitly is "new Exercise10_7().new Account"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access non static fields/properties inside static method, `main` method is static and your inner class is non static. you have two options

1. make your inner class `static`
2. access your inner class from object of your class. e.g `YourInnerClass obj = new OuterClass(). new YourInnerClass (parameters)`